# How can I prove that two null spaces are equal by using the existence of an invertible operator?

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces, linear-transformations, proof-explanation

Suppose $W$ is finite dimensional and $T_1, T_2 \in L(V,W).$ Prove that null($T_1$) $=$ null($T_2$) if and only if there exists and invertable operator $S\in L(W)$ such that $T_1 = S\circ T_2$.

---

I'm quite sure I have to make use of the rank-nullity theorem here. I started with:

$ dim(v) = dim(null(S\circ T_2)) + dim(Range(S\circ T_2)) $

$=dim(null(T_1)) + dim(Range(S \circ T_2))  $

$=dim(null(S \circ T_2) = dim(Range(nullT_1))$

$=dim(nullT_1) + dim(Range(T_1)) $

$= dim(nullT_1), + dim(Range(S \circ T_2))$

$=dim(Range(T_1)) = dim(Range(S \circ T_2))$

...I'm not sure how to take this further and put everything together.

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: Any time you're stuck on a proof, one place to start is to circle all the key terms and write down the definitions for them. PS it's "Invertible", not "invertable".